# Failed to produce a 200 status after issuing a get requests with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to send GET HTTP requests to a webpage and receive a 200 status in response. It is necessary to send appropriate parameters with the link while issuing requests. However, when I send a requests using the `link` and `payload`, I always receive a 410 status code.

When I use the URL copied from the dev tools directly in the following code, I get a 200 status.

Please note that I've modified the values of `AnchorProdSetId` and `ProdSetId` before sending payload with the link.

How can I get a 200 (403 when detected) status after issuing requests using the link with payload?

```
import json
import requests

complete_url_from_d_tools = 'https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1687879695/WebParts/Content/ContentWebPart.aspx?cntnrIDtxt=ProdPageContent&srchidtxt=5875341805879&cntnrwdth=769&srchrslttxt=screws&GrpUsrInps=[{%22AnchorProdSetId%22:%22-2674186034712253%22,%22AnchorStateIsSet%22:true,%22ClearAllProdSetId%22:-1,%22ClearAllStateIsSet%22:true,%22GrpEID%22:%22%22,%22ProdSetId%22:%22-2674186034712253%22}]&viewporthgt=192&cssAlias=undefined&usedynamicimageswapping=true&conditionalclientlandingpage=true&forcemdmfiltering=true&workstationdata=true&fwdSsToNav=true&fwdSsWpNav=true&fwdCrcWpNav=true&sortRowsOnServer=true&showbroadlandingpagecopy=true&filtSsAttrEarly=true&legImgContainsHash=true&envrmgrcharsetind=3&useEs6=true'

link = 'https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1687538569/WebParts/Content/ContentWebPart.aspx'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mcmaster.com/products/screws/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
payload = {
    'cntnrIDtxt': 'ProdPageContent',
    'srchidtxt': '5875341805879',
    'cntnrwdth': '769',
    'srchrslttxt': 'screws',
    'GrpUsrInps': '[{"AnchorProdSetId":"","AnchorStateIsSet":"true","ClearAllProdSetId":-1,"ClearAllStateIsSet":"true","GrpEID":"","ProdSetId":""}]',
    'viewporthgt': '192',
    'cssAlias': 'undefined',
    'usedynamicimageswapping': 'true',
    'conditionalclientlandingpage': 'true',
    'forcemdmfiltering': 'true',
    'workstationdata': 'true',
    'fwdSsToNav': 'true',
    'fwdSsWpNav': 'true',
    'fwdCrcWpNav': 'true',
    'sortRowsOnServer': 'true',
    'showbroadlandingpagecopy': 'true',
    'filtSsAttrEarly': 'true',
    'legImgContainsHash': 'true',
    'envrmgrcharsetind': '3',
    'useEs6': 'true',
}

payload['GrpUsrInps'] = json.loads(payload['GrpUsrInps'])
payload['GrpUsrInps'][0]['AnchorProdSetId'] = '-2674186034712253'
payload['GrpUsrInps'][0]['ProdSetId'] = '-2674186034712253'
payload['GrpUsrInps'] = json.dumps(payload['GrpUsrInps'])

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    # res = s.get(complete_url_from_d_tools)
    res = s.get(link,params=payload)
    print(res.status_code)
```

Comment: Do you want to search for the string "screws" from the main page?

Comment: I can scrape the results after searching `screws` from the main page. However, my main goal is to access any content from the inner page, as in the content displayed after clicking on `Socket Head Screws` @Andrej Kesely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this server returns brotli compressed response. To get `200` response from the server, install `brotli` package:

```
pip install brotli
```

Then:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1687879695/WebParts/Content/ContentWebPart.aspx?cntnrIDtxt=ProdPageContent&srchidtxt=5875341805879&cntnrwdth=1001&srchrslttxt=screws&GrpUsrInps=%5B%7B%22AnchorProdSetId%22%3A%22-3383254440195390%22%2C%22AnchorStateIsSet%22%3Atrue%2C%22ClearAllProdSetId%22%3A-1%2C%22ClearAllStateIsSet%22%3Atrue%2C%22GrpEID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ProdSetId%22%3A%22-3383254440195390%22%7D%5D&viewporthgt=296&cssAlias=undefined&usedynamicimageswapping=true&conditionalclientlandingpage=true&forcemdmfiltering=true&workstationdata=true&fwdSsToNav=true&fwdSsWpNav=true&fwdCrcWpNav=true&sortRowsOnServer=true&showbroadlandingpagecopy=true&filtSsAttrEarly=true&legImgContainsHash=true&clientNavigationEvents=%5B%5D&envrmgrcharsetind=5&useEs6=true"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
```

Prints:

```
200
```

---

EDIT: To get content for "Socket Head Screws":

```py
import requests

AnchorProdSetId = '-3383254440195390'
ProdSetId = '-3383254440195390'

params = {
    "cntnrIDtxt": "ProdPageContent",
    "srchidtxt": "5875341805879",
    "cntnrwdth": "1001",
    "srchrslttxt": "screws",
    "GrpUsrInps": '[{"AnchorProdSetId":"' + AnchorProdSetId + '","AnchorStateIsSet":true,"ClearAllProdSetId":-1,"ClearAllStateIsSet":true,"GrpEID":"","ProdSetId":"' + ProdSetId + '"}]',
    "viewporthgt": "296",
    "cssAlias": "undefined",
    "usedynamicimageswapping": "true",
    "conditionalclientlandingpage": "true",
    "forcemdmfiltering": "true",
    "workstationdata": "true",
    "fwdSsToNav": "true",
    "fwdSsWpNav": "true",
    "fwdCrcWpNav": "true",
    "sortRowsOnServer": "true",
    "showbroadlandingpagecopy": "true",
    "filtSsAttrEarly": "true",
    "legImgContainsHash": "true",
    "clientNavigationEvents": "[]",
    "envrmgrcharsetind": "5",
    "useEs6": "true",
}

url = 'https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1687879695/WebParts/Content/ContentWebPart.aspx'
r = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, brotli was already installed on my machine. When I issue a request using `complete_url_from_d_tools`, I get the status 200 response. The script produces status 410 when I send a requests using `link` and `payload`. I'm willing to get a 200 status in response to a requests issued by `link` and `payload`.

Comment: @robots.txt It seems you have wrong `AnchorProdSetId`/`ProdSetId`. When I  set the numbers for `"Socket Head Screws"` I get right response. I've updated my answer.